# Issue parsing Json arrays in SQL after finding keys

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I am having an issue figuring out what is the proper method to use for parsing this query. I found my keys to be 2020-10-28 and 2020-10-29. From there I wanted to cross apply the information but when I cross apply the second set it then cross applies the first cross apply. I have been trying to figure out how to apply the set up to the table as a whole and can't seem to make it uniform where I can get both the 2020-10-28 schedule and 2020-10-29 schedule in the same columns.

Any advice is appreciated

```
SELECT * FROM @json

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))

WITH (
    [2020-10-28] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON,
    [2020-10-29] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS MetaData 

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([MetaData].[2020-10-28])
WITH(
    [member_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [schedule_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [position_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [position_qualification_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [start_datetime] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [start_timestamp] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [stop_datetime] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [stop_timestamp] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [extends_before] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [extends_after] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) as October28
```

[image: Results from the first run]

```
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([MetaData].[2020-10-29])
WITH(
    [member_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [schedule_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [position_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [position_qualification_id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [start_datetime] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [start_timestamp] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [stop_datetime] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [stop_timestamp] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [extends_before] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [extends_after] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) as October29
```

[image: Results for the second cross apply]

```
{"2020-10-28":[{"member_id":79,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":11,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":268,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":72,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":258,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":73,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":223,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":10,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":118,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":12,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":29,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":2,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":168,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":100,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":174,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":1,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":183,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":3,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":178,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":89,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":286,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":93,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":282,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":101,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":189,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":91,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":119,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":90,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":92,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":38,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":291,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":121,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":33,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":37,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":263,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":107,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":228,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":39,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":287,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":140,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":297,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":142,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":231,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":143,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":307,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":144,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":327,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":146,"position_qualification_id":11,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":78,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":111,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":236,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":119,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":227,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":70,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":238,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":110,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":144,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":29,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":192,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":108,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":84,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":28,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":298,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":30,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":325,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":104,"position_qualification_id":11,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":101,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":139,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":323,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":135,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":290,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":136,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":58,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":137,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":76,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":47,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":241,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":50,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":45,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":46,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":306,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":48,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":329,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":103,"position_qualification_id":11,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":190,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":20,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":264,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":125,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":102,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":23,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T11:15","stop_timestamp":1603901700,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":65,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":19,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:45","start_timestamp":1603889100,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":38,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":21,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-28T07:30","start_timestamp":1603888200,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-28T20:00","stop_timestamp":1603933200,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false}],"2020-10-29":[{"member_id":79,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":11,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":287,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":72,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":222,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":73,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":223,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":10,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":161,"schedule_id":2,"position_id":12,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":29,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":2,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":168,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":100,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":49,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":1,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":183,"schedule_id":1,"position_id":3,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":178,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":89,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":281,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":93,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":231,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":101,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":117,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":91,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":208,"schedule_id":14,"position_id":90,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":92,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":38,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":291,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":121,"position_qualification_id":13,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":72,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":37,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":184,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":107,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":185,"schedule_id":5,"position_id":39,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":322,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":140,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":317,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":142,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":318,"schedule_id":19,"position_id":144,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":78,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":111,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":82,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":119,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":227,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":70,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":224,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":110,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":327,"schedule_id":10,"position_id":114,"position_qualification_id":11,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":144,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":29,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":192,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":108,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":84,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":28,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T11:30","stop_timestamp":1603989000,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":232,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":28,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T11:30","start_timestamp":1603989000,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":48,"schedule_id":4,"position_id":30,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":277,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":139,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":279,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":135,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T14:00","stop_timestamp":1603998000,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":258,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":135,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T14:00","start_timestamp":1603998000,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":309,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":136,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":81,"schedule_id":18,"position_id":137,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":233,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":47,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":197,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":50,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":297,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":46,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":58,"schedule_id":6,"position_id":48,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":91,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":20,"position_qualification_id":2,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":278,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":23,"position_qualification_id":5,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":65,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":19,"position_qualification_id":1,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:45","start_timestamp":1603975500,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":128,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":21,"position_qualification_id":3,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false},{"member_id":313,"schedule_id":3,"position_id":109,"position_qualification_id":11,"start_datetime":"2020-10-29T07:30","start_timestamp":1603974600,"stop_datetime":"2020-10-29T20:00","stop_timestamp":1604019600,"extends_before":false,"extends_after":false}]}
```

Comment: Is all of your data *really* up to 2GB in size? What sort of "date" is a `[stop_datetime]` if it might be 1 Billion characters long?

Comment: Most of it is two to fifteen characters except for the 2020-10-28, and the 2020-10-29

Comment: So why declare it as an `nvarchar(MAX)`? If it's a date, you have 6 date and time data types to choose from which would be way for appropriate.

Comment: That's a good point I will adjust it, I was focusing on the parsing and ignored it to get to parsing faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach to parse the input JSON is to use `OPENJSON()` twice:

- With default schema - to get the variable keys (`"2020-10-28"`, `"2020-10-29"`, ...)
- With explicit schema (using the appropriate data types) and additional `APPLY` operator - to parse the content of each nested JSON array.

Note, that the exact statement depends on the expected result.

```
SELECT j1.[key] AS [current_date], j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    [member_id] int,
    [schedule_id] int,
    [position_id] int,
    [position_qualification_id] int,
    [start_datetime] varchar(16),
    [start_timestamp] bigint,
    [stop_datetime] varchar(16),
    [stop_timestamp] bigint,
    [extends_before] bit,
    [extends_after] bit
) j2
```

Result:

```
current_date member_id schedule_id position_id position_qualification_id start_datetime   start_timestamp stop_datetime    stop_timestamp extends_before extends_after
2020-10-28   79        2           11          2                         2020-10-28T07:45 1603889100      2020-10-28T20:00 1603933200       False          False
2020-10-28   268       2           72          13                        2020-10-28T07:45 1603889100      2020-10-28T20:00 1603933200     False        False
.........
2020-10-29   313       3           109         11                        2020-10-29T07:30 1603974600      2020-10-29T20:00 1604019600     False          False
```

Comment: Thank you for your helps and the explanation, its running perfectly now